# How do I put objects on the map in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, game-physics

I'm building a game where the player has to put different objects on the map.

I have already set up the map and it has 2 layers, second layer is for placing objects. There is also a sidebar to select the object to put on the map. However, I'm trying to find an easiest way to realise it, since the objects I want to put on the map consist of set of tiles.

Comment: I think this question needs a little more context. Are you working with com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap and your question is about how to add cells to a layer?